# Migrate data from DB2 to SQL Server - What's needed on DB2 side?

Tags: sql-server, db2, database-migration

I need to move a lot of data from an OLD DB2 server to SQL Server.  I'd like to create a linked server using the OLE DB Provider for DB2 on my SQL Server.  What I don't know is what is required on the DB2 side.  The DB2 server belongs to another organization and most of the people that worked with it have retired.  The version is "DB2 for VSE 6.1".  Can I connect to that from SQL Server by default?  If not, is there optional software that can be installed that will provide connectivity?  I believe I need DRDA application server support, but that is all I have been able to find so far.  Because of the volume of data, I would prefer not to use intermediate text files if possible.  Are there other options that will work with V6.1?

Comment: I found out the server does not have TCP/IP, so this is a no-go.  If it had TCP/IP, I believe DB2 Connect (Personal Edition on my PC or higher version on the server) would have been needed for me to use one of the Microsoft DB2 providers.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use SSIS, which can be available or not, depending on your SQL Server Edition, I recommend you to use this tool for moving the data. It help you handle of the complexities of data type changes, conversions, validations...

As far as what you need to connect to DB2, [have a look at this](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/700/connecting-to-db2-using-ssis). It not only explains how to use SSIS to connect to DB2, but also explain where you can download a DB2 driver.

I can't assure this driver will work with you particular version of DB2.

[Look also here](http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/05/16/connecting-to-db2-from-ssis.aspx).

Comment: Whether it will work with DB2 for VSE 6.1 is my primary question.  I use SQL Server extensively, but have no experience with DB2/IBM.  I appreciate the links though.  If I get that far they will be helpful.

Comment: In those link you get info on how to get the drivers. You don't need to use SSIS, but I encourage you to use it. It's a great tool for moving data around, and it's not too hard to learn.